# JBoss - Wrong cxf.xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jboss, cxf

i have two EARs with a WebService on jboss as 4.2.3 deployed (Webservice A and B).

webservice A has a cxf.xml in the ear. 
When i deploy webservice B the cxf.xml from A is used and Webservice B is not working.

```
 [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.DescriptorDeploymentAspect] CXF configuration found: jar:file://.....server/default/tmp/deploy/ApplicationA.ear....
```

when i deploy only application B, jboss autogenerate a cxf.xml and everthing is working.

How can i get Webservice B always autogenerating a cxf.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with JBoss in a while, but it may be that you are hitting a problem where the class loaders are not isolated properly.

Based on [this article](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration), I would suggest that you try isolating the classloaders by adding

```
<jboss-app>
   <loader-repository> 
   com.example:archive=unique-archive-name 
   </loader-repository> 
</jboss-app>
```

in `jboss-app.xml`.